# Reorder data frame by compressing 1 column and transposing remaining columns

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose, reshape2

I have a small data frame in R that consists of two treatment conditions and the corresponding time point and mean gene expression of a specific gene for those samples.

```
> RPmean
```

Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: Treatment [?]

```
    Treatment time.num gExp.mean
       (fctr)    (dbl)     (dbl)
1 cigarette_smoke        1  10.96147
2 cigarette_smoke        2  11.32251
3 cigarette_smoke        4  11.16829
4 cigarette_smoke       24  10.88674
5         control        1  11.09731
6         control        2  10.99542
7         control        4  10.79247
8         control       24  11.25574
```

I'd like to rearrange it so that the treatment column lists just one instance of cig_smoke and control, and that the time.num and g.Expmean are transposed into rows.

```
Something like this
Treatment             1     2      4     24
cigarette_smoke      10     11     10     11
control               9      ##    ##     ##
```

I was trying to suss it out in reshape, but haven't had any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of reshaping can be handled pretty efficiently with `spread` from the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
dat %>% spread(time.num, gExp.mean)
#         Treatment        1        2        4       24
# 1 cigarette_smoke 10.96147 11.32251 11.16829 10.88674
# 2         control 11.09731 10.99542 10.79247 11.25574
```